# Insert Cells based on Active Row/s

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code here:

```
Sub ShoveActiveRight()

Range("A" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Select
ActiveCell.Columns(2).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
ActiveCell.Columns(5).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

End Sub`
```

This will send the user back to column A and then shove everything in column B onward to the right. Then do the same for everything in Column E onward to the right.

I need this exact same thing, except I need to be able to select a range of cells, so that it does this to every row in the range.

I.E. if i select cell A7, B7 moves to the right, leaving a blank and E7 moves to the right leaving a blank, with all the rest of my data appropriate moved 1 and then 2 to the right.
If i select cells A7:A9 then I need B7:B9 to move to the right etc.

Hope this makes sense!
Appreciate any help you can offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to work with `Selection` to get the selected range instead of only the active cell (which is always a single cell). And use the [Range.Offset property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) to move relatively from the selection.

```
Sub ShoveActiveRangeRight()
    
    With Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column) ' this moves to column A of the selected range
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight ' this moves from column a 1 right and inserts
        .Offset(ColumnOffset:=4).Insert Shift:=xlToRight ' this moves from column a 4 right and inserts
    End With

End Sub
```

Or if the following is better readable for you (it does exactly the same)

```
Sub ShoveActiveRangeRight()
    Dim ColumnAOfSelectedRange As Range
    Set ColumnAOfSelectedRange = Selection.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1 - Selection.Column)

    ColumnAOfSelectedRange.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ColumnAOfSelectedRange.Offset(ColumnOffset:=4).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to solve my issue, very speedy and super helpful, cheers!

Comment: Out of interest, since it seems using vba overwrites the ability of ctrl-z, what would be the reverse of this? In case someone accidentally did the inserts on a row they didn't mean to adjust?

Comment: @Kovu just `.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft` instead of insert. You might need to adjust the `ColumnOffset`. But carefull this is no real undo, as if the user clicks somewhere else after insert, then the selection changed and if he runs the delete code it will delete actual data! So that might cause more trouble than you want.